# Show $\{ T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n) \}$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a linearly independant set of vectors spanning $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $T \in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $T$ is also invertible.

Prove that  $\{ T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n) \}$ is linearly independent if and only if $T$ is invertible.

I dont really know how to approach this.
I figure i can prove one direction by setting $T$ to be invertible then maybe using the defintions of one-to-one and onto...but i am still not sure how to apply this.

Comment: this follows immediately from the definitions. Start by setting the usual equation for linear independence and use your hypothesis as you need them. If you get stuck feel free to ask.

Comment: This is not true. (Pick $n=1$, and $v_1\not=\vec0$ such that $T(v_1)\not=\vec0$.) I think you also need to assume that the set $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ spans $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Good catch I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: I think you mean spanning V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a dependence $c_1T(v_1)+\dots+c_nT(v_n)=0$.  By linearity, this gives $T(c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n)=0$.

On one hand, if $T$ is invertible, then it is one-to-one, so $c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n=0$.  By independence of these vectors, we have $c_1=\dots=c_n=0$, and so $\{T(v_1),\dots,T_(v_n)\}$ is independent.

On the other... $T$ need not be invertible if $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is merely an independent set and not also a *spanning* set.  For instance, $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $T(x,y)=(x,0)$ with the independent set $\{(1,0)\}$ -- this has $\{T(1,0)\}$ an independent set, too.

Though if we do go and assume $\{T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)\}$ is a spanning set as well, then for any vector $w\in V$ we may write it as $w=c_1 T(v_1)+\dots+c_n T(v_n)$ for some scalars $c_1,\dots,c_n$, which are unique by independence.  By linearity, $w=T(c_1v_1+\dots+c_n v_n)$.  Thus, $T$ is invertible: this $c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n$ is $T^{-1}(w)$, and this can be done for each $w\in V$.

Answer (score 0):

If there is some set of non trivial $a_1,....,a_n$ with 
$a_1T(v_1)+.....+a_nT(v_n)=0$, then

$T(a_1v_1)+.....+T(a_nv_n)=0\Rightarrow 
T(a_1v_1+.....+a_nv_n)$ all by the linearity of $T$. Now what can you say about the kernel of an invertible linear map?

Comment: Does the kernel have dimension 0?

Comment: yes, 0 is the only think that maps to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $T$ is invertible, and suppose 
$$c_1 T(v_1) + c_2 T(v_2) + \cdots c_n T(v_n) = \vec0.$$
The goal is to prove that all the $c_i$'s are zero. But $T$ is a linear transformation, so  the above equation is equal to
$$T(c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_n v_n) = \vec 0.$$
$T$ is invertible, so 
$$c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_n v_n = \vec0.$$
But the $v_i$'s are linearly independent, so all the $c_i$'s are zero.

For the reverse implication, suppose $T$ is not invertible. That means $T$ is not one-to-one, so there is a nonzero vector $u$ such that $T(u)=\vec0$. Write $$u = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_n v_n.$$
Then 
$$\vec0 = T(u) = T(c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_n v_n)
= c_1 T(v_1) + c_2 T(v_2) + \cdots + c_n T(v_n).$$
Since $u\not=\vec0$, and $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent, not all of the $c_i$'s are zero. This implies $\{T(v_1), T(v_2),\ldots, T(v_n)\}$ is linearly dependent.